# Powershell script does not recognize System.Windows.Forms.Form when run from Command Prompt window

Tags: windows, powershell

I can run the following PowerShell script "ExampleA.ps1` from a Command Prompt window.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System 
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms 
Class MyForm
{
    [Object] $theForm
    MyForm()
    {
        $this.theForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    }
    ShowDialog()
    {
        $this.theForm.ShowDialog()
    }
}
$theForm = New-Object myForm    
$theForm.ShowDialog()
```

The command I used is given below.

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ExampleA.ps1
```

The result is the form shown below.

[image: a1]

I would rather use inheritance in my script. If I do so, I get the script file `ExampleB.ps1` shown below.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System 
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms 
Class MyForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
}
$theForm = New-Object myForm
$theForm.ShowDialog()
```

The problem is when I run this script from a Command Prompt window, then I get the following error message.

```
C:\Users\david\Desktop\test>powershell  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ExampleB.ps1
At C:\Users\david\Desktop\test\ExampleB.ps1:3 char:16
+ Class MyForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.Form].
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Why can I not inherit System.Windows.Forms.Form`?

The same problem occurs when I try to replace `[Object]` with `[System.Windows.Forms.Form]` in `ExampleA.ps1`. Doing so, produces `ExampleC.ps1` shown below.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System 
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms 
Class MyForm
{
    [System.Windows.Forms.Form] $theForm
    MyForm()
    {
        $this.theForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    }
    ShowDialog()
    {
        $this.theForm.ShowDialog()
    }
}
$theForm = New-Object myForm
$theForm.ShowDialog()
```

When I run this script from a Command Prompt window, then I get the following error message.

```
C:\Users\david\Desktop\test>powershell  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ExampleC.ps1
At C:\Users\david\Desktop\test\ExampleC.ps1:5 char:6
+     [System.Windows.Forms.Form] $theForm
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.Form].
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Why can I not declare `System.Windows.Forms.Form`?

> Note: I do realize all three of these scripts run without error from a Windows PowerShell command prompt and from the Windows PowerShell ISE. The problem is that I need to run the scripts from the original Windows Command prompt window.

I am use the current version of 64 bit Windows 10. The output from the `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` command is given below.

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17134  228
```

Comment: I think the linked question is in essence the same problem - we can revisit if it isn't. In short: Unfortunately, the WinForms assembly must already be loaded into the session _before_ your script is executed - a constraint that will hopefully go away in future PowerShell versions, but only in PowerShell _Core_.

Comment: I think you can also define your classes in C# and add it through Add-Type. Otherwise just use functions instead of classes, and it will work with Powershell 3 as well.